# Setting value to variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can one set the `device_token` field in the below php statement to a variable named `$token`?

```
result = query("SELECT device_token, IdPhoto, IdUser FROM photos ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 1") ;
```

Based off of the w3schools SQL documentation: `The WHERE clause is used to extract only those records that fulfill a specified criterion.` How can that be used in the above code?

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Comment: Your select query will return 50 records , which value you want to set in `$token`

Comment: I want to store the device_token value in $token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a specific token you need a `WHERE` clause and a specific `userid`.

```
$id = 1; //You may get this from a form/session you created for login user    
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'password');    
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT device_token, IdPhoto, IdUser 
                       FROM photos WHERE IdUser='$id' 
                       ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 1");
$devicetoken = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $devicetoken['device_token'];
```

But if you don't need a specific token and want to return all the tokens, you don't need `WHERE` clause and `LIMIT`. However, `LIMIT` gives you the options for changing the number of rows the statement would return.

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT device_token, IdPhoto, IdUser 
                       FROM photos
                       ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC");
$token = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//store the device token here in $token
```

Now devicetoken contains an array of all the device_token. You can access each one of them using foreach loop and and while:

```
 foreach($token as $key=>$val){
      echo $val.'<br>';
 }
```